# Install bind9 on a machine that has no internet connection

Tags: linux, bind9

I need to install bind9 on a machine that has no internet connection.

I downloaded the source code and want to compile it on this machine, but there is no C compiler on my machine. And as I have no internet connection, I cannot install gcc (manual install is too difficult).

How should I do this? Is there a way that I can compile everything on another machine and move all the binaries?
Thanks

Comment: Can you not just download the package for your linux distro and install it from that?

Comment: @Eric Renouf Then how to download the package with all its dependencies?

Comment: Presumably the same way you downloaded the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Keryx](https://launchpad.net/keryx), it's an offline packet repository which permits you to firstly download `bind9` and push it to your offline workstation (assuming you're on a Debian based distro).